# link function assigned to scope is not accessible inside controller constructor function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a controller constructor function.
Also have a directive for some dom manipulation.

when we call link function deleteNotification from controller, its giving error

> deleteNotification is not a function.

How can we get the scope of link function here in controller and access method deleteNotification.

any help would be appreciated.

How can we get the scope of link function here in controller and access method deleteNotification.

```
export class triggeredNotificationController{
    constructor($scope){
       this.$scope = $scope
       this.deleteNotification();
    }
    deleteNotification(){
       self.$scope.deleteNotification();
    }
}

triggeredNotificationController.$inject=['$scope'];

cModule.controller('triggeredNotificationController',triggeredNotificationController)

cModuleAlertsModule.directive('deleteNotification',[
    function(){
        return {
            scope: false,
            controller: triggeredNotificationController,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
                scope.deleteNotification=  function(selectedRowData){
                    //some dom manipulation
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
export default cvModuleAlertsModule;
```

Comment: link is executed AFTER controller. You could use $timeout or $scope.$watch .

Comment: If you don't need to use `$compile`, you don't really need of `link`, if you write well your template.

Comment: I had to use $compile for some reason, now that need to use $timeout..Could you please explain with an answer please

Answer (score 0):

One can use the `$postLink` life-cycle hook to delay the invocation of the function:

```
export class triggeredNotificationController{
    constructor($scope){
       this.$scope = $scope
    }
    $postLink(){
       this.$scope.deleteNotification();
    }
}
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)